# Unable to install Faker with command pip install Faker

Tags: python, django, pip, faker

The problem I have is that i am unable to install `Faker` in my virtual environment with pip. I've checked pip works for other packages but is unable to install Faker

```
(MyEnv) C:\Users\cipher\PycharmProjects\udemydjango1\first_project>pip install Faker
```

```
python version:3.8.1
pip version:20.2.1
django version:3.1
```

Whenever I go to terminal and and type `pip install Faker` I receive this:

```
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\cipher\anaconda3\envs\MyEnv\python.exe C:\Users\cipher\anac
onda3\envs\MyEnv\Scripts\pip-script.py install Faker'
```

What's wrong here?Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your command line in IDE launcher:

**Do understand that this command is only a workaround.**

`python -m pip install faker`

Pip is a python package installer. It is required for all the users in Windows 10. So,to avoid this, you should reinstall Python x64 and check `for all users` in the advanced option. It will enable pip for all users.

Let me know in the comments if it helped or not.

Comment: @SushmitaPoudel If it did, I would like you please accept this as an answer. It will help me a lot.